# input text from one textfield to multi label ( in swift )

Tags: xcode, swift

in xcode with swift, How to send text from textfield to the first label by pressing button, and send text to the second label by pressing the button for the second time - 
[image: example]

i try this and it's work with empty labels only .

```
@IBAction func btn(sender: AnyObject) {

if l1.text == ""
{ l1.text=txt.text}

else if l2.text == ""
{ l2.text=txt.text}

else  if l3.text == ""
{ l3.text=txt.text}

else if l4.text == ""
{ l4.text=txt.text}

}
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 1
@IBAction func btn(sender: AnyObject) {
    switch i {
        case 1:
            l1.text=txt.text
            i++
        case 2:
            l2.text=txt.text
            i++
        case 3:
            l3.text=txt.text
            i++
        case 4:
            l4.text=txt.text
            i++
        default:
            i = 1
    }
}
```

I did not check it, but it must works for you